# How much time does it take to review flags for questions?

Tags: discussion

I am wondering about how much time Stack Overflow takes to review flags on questions (as opposed to answers)?

So, when one raises a flag on a question, what is the average time until it is handled?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're asking? Do you mean in general/or a specific type of flag or...?

Comment: As fast as having enough reviewers do the review (which usually is fast, under 1 hour?), except for close-vote review queue (nearly forever)

Comment: @AndrewT. not specific flags..i am asking about any kind of flags which is related  to questions only

Comment: [6-8 weeks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/295232) ...

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question. I think you're asking the average time between flagging a question and the flag being handled?

Comment: @S.L.Barth exactly

Comment: @Aditya Im sure there is such a time, but its mostly usless for predicting how long flags will take to get handled. Its generally random, depending on the type of flag and activity on the question/answer you flagged. If you flag a off-topic question on a popular tag for closure, that flag can get handled in seconds, for instance.

Comment: Sometime this will never happen. Over 100 flags "aged away" for me :)

Comment: Depends also on how many Aditya's are willing to do reviewing ;)

Comment: Flags are reviewed when other users act on them.  Some flags are community handled while others can only be handled by diamond mods.  Either way, there's a human element to handling (most) flags.  But I'd say a few minutes for the really obvious cases and a few hours for custom flags or borderline cases.

Comment: @Aditya Are you talking about close flags/votes? Or any flag tied to a question?  Comparing it to answers would be odd because questions go to the Close Review queue when flagged/voted for closure which is incredibly large.  Since that queue is so much larger than other queues which handle answers, these tend to linger a bit longer.